# Will a bash-script continue execution even if the go-routine it is defined within is killed?

Tags: bash, go, operating-system, goroutine

I am running a Go application which has multiple Go routines . In one of the go-routines we are executing a bash script using the os.exec command which on one particular condition will kill the main thread of the application using SIGKILL (kill -9) and respawn the application once more . My doubt is whether the bash script will resume its operations once the goroutine is killed or will it also be stopped.

Comment: a process cannot catch a sigkill, thus it cannot "forward" the signal to its chidren. You script will probably remain alive (unless a side effect has it to die like broken pipe or else..)

Answer (score 1):

A process has a [Kill()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Kill) method that needs to be invoked to stop the script. So by killing the parent process, you'll be leaking the child processes.